# Monitoring params via JMX

Tags: java, plugin

A task for hiring on a new job (I failed it with reason "very bad code").

*Write a program, which will be  monitoring the params via JMX.
Param should have name, type and observabale value.*

**Why my code is bad? And how write this task more eleganty and clear?**

---

**main.java** 
Starts my app

```
public class Main {
    public static String pluginFolder;
    public static Integer port = 9999;
    public static void main( String args[] )
    {
        //directory with plugins
        if (args.length>0) {
            pluginFolder = args[0];
        } else {
            System.out.println("Please specify folder with plugins! Type path to plugins after space");
            return;
        }

        //port number
        if (args.length>1) {
            try {
                Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
            } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
                Utils.showMessage("Wrong port. Using default port: " + port);
            }
        }

        MBeanContainer.startMBeanServer();
    }
}
```

**MBeanContainer.java**

There is MBeanServer, where controls observable params. We can start, stop MBeanServer and pass or get params from it.

```
public class MBeanContainer
{
    static MBeanServer mBeanServer;
    private static HashMap<ParamInterface, BaseParam> mbeansList = new HashMap<ParamInterface, BaseParam>();

    /**
     * Start Mbean server
     */
    public static void startMBeanServer() {
        mBeanServer = ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer();
        try {
            LocateRegistry.createRegistry(Main.port);
            JMXServiceURL url = new JMXServiceURL("service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://localhost:"+Main.port+"/server");
            JMXConnectorServer cs = JMXConnectorServerFactory.newJMXConnectorServer(url, null, mBeanServer);
            cs.start();
        } catch (ExportException ee) { //hide trace exception and continue work when mbean server is already run.
            if (ee.getCause().getClass() == BindException.class)
            Utils.showMessage("Server is already started. \n " + ee.getCause().getMessage() + " \n continue...");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Utils.processException(e);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Register mbean in server
     * @param baseParam
     */
    public static void registerMbean(ParamInterface baseParam)  {
        BaseParam mbeanObj = new BaseParam(baseParam);
        try {
            ObjectName mbeanName = new ObjectName("JMXParam:name="+baseParam.getType());
            mBeanServer.registerMBean(mbeanObj, mbeanName);
            mBeanServer.addNotificationListener(mbeanName, new ParamListener(), null, null);
            mbeansList.put(baseParam, mbeanObj);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Utils.processException(e);
        }
    }


    /**
     * Return Mbean object by type of plugin
     * @param type
     * @return
     */
    public static BaseParam getParamMBeanByType(String type){
        for(Map.Entry<ParamInterface, BaseParam> entry : mbeansList.entrySet()) {
            if (entry.getKey().getType().equals(type)) {
                return entry.getValue();
            }
        }
        Utils.log("getParamMBeanByType return null for param type: " + type);
        return null; //never unreached
    }

    public static void stopMonitoring(){
        for(BaseParam mbean: mbeansList.values()){
            mbean.stop();
        }
    }

    public static void startMonitoring(){
        for(BaseParam mbean: mbeansList.values()){
            mbean.start();
        }
    }

}
```

**ParamInterface.java**
Interface which all params should be implement

```
public interface ParamInterface {
    public int getInterval();
    public String getName();
    public String getType();
    public String getValue();
}
```

**BaseParamMBean**

Interface of working with param.

```
public interface BaseParamMBean
{
    public void start();
    public void stop();
    public void setInterval( long time );
}
```

**BaseParam.java** Observable param. Superclass for params. Can generate notifications and send them to server. Take an instance of ParamInterface in constructor as specialazed version of the param. Can stop, start, and change interval of sending events.

```
    public class BaseParam extends NotificationBroadcasterSupport implements BaseParamMBean, Runnable
    {
        private boolean stop = true;
        private int index = 0;
        private long interval = 1000;
        private String paramName;
        private String paramType;
        private String oldValue;
        private ParamInterface o;

        public BaseParam(ParamInterface o)
        {
            this.paramName = o.getName();
            this.paramType = o.getType();
            this.interval = o.getInterval();
            this.o = o;
            this.start();
        }

        public void setInterval( long interval )
        {
            this.interval = interval;
        }
        public void start()
        {
            try
            {
                stop = false;
                Thread t = new Thread( this );
                t.start();
            }
            catch( Exception e )
            {
               Utils.processException(e);
            }
        }

        public void stop()
        {
            stop = true;
        }

        public void run()
        {
            while( !stop )
            {
                try
                {
                    Thread.sleep(interval);
                }
                catch( Exception e )
                {
                    Utils.processException(e);
                }

                String newValue = o.getValue();
                AttributeChangeNotification notif = new AttributeChangeNotification(
                        this, //object
                        index, //sequenceNumber
                        System.currentTimeMillis(), //cur time
                        "Attribute Change", //msg
                        this.paramName, //attributeName
                        this.paramType, //attributeType
                        oldValue, //old value
                        newValue //new value
                );
                sendNotification(notif);
                oldValue = newValue;
            }//while
        }

         public MBeanNotificationInfo[] getNotificationInfo()
        {
            String[] attChanges = { AttributeChangeNotification.ATTRIBUTE_CHANGE };
            MBeanNotificationInfo[] info = new MBeanNotificationInfo[1];
            info[ 0 ] = new MBeanNotificationInfo(attChanges, "javax.management.AttributeChangeNotification", this.paramName);
            return info;
        }

}
```

**ParamListener**

Listener shows event from params to console.

```
public class ParamListener implements NotificationListener {

    public void handleNotification( Notification not, Object obj )
    {
        AttributeChangeNotification notif = (AttributeChangeNotification) not;
        System.out.println(notif.getAttributeName()+": "+notif.getNewValue());
        CustomTable.updateCell(notif.getAttributeType(), notif.getNewValue().toString());
    }
}
```

**Utils**

```
public class Utils {

    public static void processException(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    public static void showMessage(String s) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }

    public static void log(String s) {
        System.out.println("!" + s);
    }
}
```

**CpuParam**

Implementation of concrete param

```
public class CpuParam implements ParamInterface {

    private int maximum = 100;
    private int minimum = 0;
    private final String name = "CPU load";
    private final String type = "cpu.attribute.check";
    private int interval = 5000;

    @Override
    public int getInterval() {
        return interval;
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    @Override
    public String getValue() {
        Random rn = new Random();
        int range = maximum - minimum + 1;
        int randomNum =  rn.nextInt(range) + minimum;
        return String.valueOf(randomNum);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

### Stylistic

- (Always assuming this is not garbled by the pasting) there is
  inconsistent indentation in some places, parameter lists sometimes
  have spaces, sometimes they don't and the names aren't that great
  (e.g. `not` for notification, `o`, `cs` are bad).
- The comments aren't very useful, except for the one in
  `MBeanContainer`, `//hide trace...`, because it actually clarifies
  the intent. I'd also either remove incomplete docstrings, or fill them
  in. IMO if they don't add to the understanding of the code, they just
  add clutter, but you could argue differently if you actually used the
  docstrings in the IDE or docs generation.
- Catching `Exception` at every turn suggests that the error handling
  isn't well structured. If you can't deal with the error, let it
  propagate and don't just print a stack trace (or at least re-throw so
  the caller can deal with it).
- In `MBeanContainer` the type check for `BindException` should probably
  be changed to use `instanceof`. Also, what's with the alternative
  case?
- Better use the base interface instead of specific classes when you
  write out the types, e.g. `Map<ParamInterface, BaseParam>`. Again, I'm
  pretty sure you don't rely on the hashing part. With one of the latest
  changes in Java you can also omit a lot of the generic arguments.
- If you use `final` once, either do it always, or not at all. Same for
  `@Override`.
- `BaseParam` copies the values from `ParamInterface` *and* stores the
  object itself. Again, choose one or the other.

### Structural

- `getInterval` returns an `int`, `setInterval` accepts `long`. The
  parameter is named `time` in the interface, `interval` in the
  implementation. Renaming to `milliseconds` would be good, showing off
  `JodaTime` or a cron library would be great for an interview exercise
  I guess, although for millisecond resolution it's overkill.
- `MBeanContainer` is all global and `static`. Changing that to regular
  methods and maybe providing a singleton will make this way more
  reusable.
- `BaseParam::run` does too much, I'd split the notification creation
  into a method so the control flow is more obvious.

Okay, maybe others find more. Providing tests would also be something
nice to show off.

Even though this is an interview exercise, I think at least these points
would need to be addressed before considering using it in production and
later maintaining it.

Thread safety is probably okay, but is something to look out for. It
would be nice if `stopMonitoring` actually waited for threads to
shutdown.

For the design itself, well, without a bit more restrictions it's hard
to see what should be changed; apart from what I wrote it looks okay to
me. JMX probably isn't the best thing to exercise anyway.

Answer (score 3):

First impressions can make a huge impact when assessing someone's code. Let's look at your Main class:

> ```
> public class Main {
>     public static String pluginFolder;
>     public static Integer port = 9999;
>     public static void main( String args[] )
>     {
>         //directory with plugins
>         if (args.length>0) {
>             pluginFolder = args[0];
>         } else {
>             System.out.println("Please specify folder with plugins! Type path to plugins after space");
>             return;
>         }
>
>         //port number
>         if (args.length>1) {
>             try {
>                 Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
>             } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
>                 Utils.showMessage("Wrong port. Using default port: " + port);
>             }
>         }
>
>         MBeanContainer.startMBeanServer();
>     }
> }
> ```

The first thing I notice is that you have two static fields, and that they are public, and not final.

Static fields should be uncommon, and, when they exist they should be final. If they are not final, they should at least be private....

In your check to find the pluginFolder, that's almost OK. The `return` from the main method is not what I would expect, though. If there's a problem, I would expect a non-zero exit code.. `System.exit(1)`, or perhaps an exception.

The Port number check is more concerning:

> ```
>     if (args.length>1) {
>         try {
>             Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
>         } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
>             Utils.showMessage("Wrong port. Using default port: " + port);
>         }
>     }
> ```

You use a Utils class here for this message, but not if there's no `args[0]`?

Additionally, if the `args[1]` here successfully parses as an int, you don not actually save the value to `port`... you just throw it away. So, even though you say you support changing the port number, you never actually change the port number.

Finally, what should you have done in the main method?

At minimum, I would have preferred to see the code:

```
private static final int DEFAULT_PORT = 9999;

public static void main (String args[]) {

    if (args.length == 0) {
        Utils.showMessage("Usage: prog plugin_folder {port}");
        System.exit(1);
    }

    int port = DEFAULT_PORT;
    if (args.length > 1) {
        try {
            port = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
        } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
            Utils.showMessage("Wrong port. Using default port: " + port);
        }
    }

    MBeanContainer.startMBeanServer(args[0], port);
}
```

Then, your `startMBeanServer(...)` method does not need to access the public static fields on the `Main` class.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose this was a homework assignment.
I do this too when looking for talent.
Instead of the extreme pressure of writing code on the spot at the interview,
I give the opportunity to do your best in your private time,
in your most comfortable environment.
And I expect nothing less than a piece of beauty in return.

There are a couple things that you can do almost effortlessly that will make a big difference:

- Apply standard formatting using the built in functions of your IDE. For example Control-Shift-f in Eclipse, Control-Alt-l in IntelliJ. Apply to all your files.
- Eliminate all warnings your IDE gives you.
- Eliminate even more issues: install the FindBugs plugin in Eclipse. In IntelliJ (I'm talking about the free community edition here) the default warnings are already pretty strict.
- Add a couple of unit tests. And not just any unit tests, make them good.

Except for the unit tests, the above items are actually pretty mechanical:
any monkey can do them. Yet, you haven't. This seriously crippled your chances from the start.

Here are a couple more things on top of the other excellent reviews by [@ferada](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/54571/ferada) and [@rolfl](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/31503/rolfl). But you should also follow the above suggestions, as they will uncover even more.

---

> ```
> private static HashMap<ParamInterface, BaseParam> mbeansList = new HashMap<ParamInterface, BaseParam>();
> ```

Use interface types in variable and method parameter declarations whenever possible (most of the time).
And, when submitting for a job application,
choose a current Java version.
Today, that should be at least Java 7,
in which case your IDE would tell you to use the diamond operator when creating instances.

```
private static Map<ParamInterface, BaseParam> mbeansList = new HashMap<>();
```

---

Reduce the number of connections between your classes.
For example, `Main` depends on `MBeanContainer`, but `MBeanContainer` also depends on `Main` (for the `port` setting).
In this example `Main` should have passed all the necessary parameters to `MBeanContainer`.
This is a particularly bad example,
because a class like `Main` is effectively just a throw-away launcher:
its sole purpose is to start up the "machinery" of a program / framework,
and *nothing should depend on it*.

---

Avoid unused stuff.
Every single line of code in a program may potentially introduce a bug,
and it inevitably adds to the complexity.
Look for unused elements and remove them.
Especially for a job interview,
there's no place for speculation about potential future uses.
Leave in what has purpose,
leave out everything that doesn't.

For example in `Main`,
you save `args[0]` in `pluginFolder`, but then you never use it.
Similarly, you parse `args[1]`, but you never use it.

See, that `Main` class gave you a lot more problems than it solved.
It's kind of crazy, but honestly, this trivial implementation would have been a level of magnitude better:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        MBeanContainer.startMBeanServer(9999);
    }
}
```

With so little code, this is a lot harder to pick on.
This also effectively eliminates the possibility of another class referencing `Main.blah`.
As a general rule: the less code you have, the better.
(Less code meaning less logic, less unused stuff. Not "clever" syntax that hurts readability.)

Comment: janos, thanks a lot for your usefull answer!!!
I also am confused of my approach with exceptions. Should I generate catch exceptions as I did, or some better way exists?

Comment: At the minimum, stop catching `Exception`s. Catch the specific sub-types of `Exception` that are being thrown. Also consider what is the best way to handle them rather than just logging / printing, and if it makes sense to catch them or let them bubble up in the call stack.